# Visual Studio Code - launch.json and debugger is stuck on Python

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code

When I installed Visual Studio Code I configured it for Python. Now when I try to use it for Node.js it still thinks I am trying to debug Python.

Also it is stuck on the original *launch.json* file from another directory. I tried adding a configuration for Node.js, but Visual Studio Code is still using the Python launch configuration in the other directory.

Additionally the Debug pick list only has options for Python.  I looked at *[Launch.json in Visual Studio Code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34732849/launch-json-in-visual-studio-code)*, but it doesn't solve my problem.

[Language Picklist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c2QYk.png)

I need help because I've been tasked to start learning Node.js.

Answer (score 0):

In order to get Visual Studio Code to debug JavaScript, delete the .vscode folder which deletes the *launch.json* file.

For some reason, Visual Studio Code remembers the last *launch.json* file and tries to use it.